# Sharing data between android apps without server database

Tags: android

I wants share data between users that installed my android application. Users can be anywhere in the world. I know that i can do this by storing data on server and then pushing that info to other users. But i don't want to use server. Can this be possible.

Comment: Not realistically, as 99% of mobile networks will not route incomming connections, thus precluding traffic between most peers.  Even so-called "hole punching" requires the aid of a server to start the process.  But you don't need your own server for simple data exchange - there are countless services out there you can use with different capabilities and business terms.

Answer (score 0):

Technically its impossible, you don't need a physical server but you need a cloud storage which is basically a server somewhere else in the world.. there are many companies who provide cloud storage services like Microsoft - Microsoft Azure, Google - Google App Engine, Go-daddy, etc. And if your app is small you might not have to pay anything at all because both Microsoft and Google provides you with a free tier which has a certain limit of free storage and other services.. i recommend Google App engine for android app development. :)